# How to send an email with a link to reset password in PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, reset-password

I love exploring the world of PHP through [my website](http://benoitmignault.ca/login/login.php?langue=english) by creating small projects personal who give me experience for the current and future work who knows ...

I will add very soon the information of email when a user creates an account on my website...

After a few hours of research and reading, I can not find or understand how to send an email with a link to reset the password of a user...

Here is my method of hashing:

```
$options = ['cost' => 11, 'salt' => random_bytes(22)];
$passwordCrypter = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

I think we need to use this method because to decrypt a password is not recommended I think...

But why...I want to understand...

Thx

Have a nice guys

Comment: don't decrypt passwords, hash the user input and compare that hash with the one in the database

Comment: I think you should send reset password link on the email, and you can setup new password on reset form submit.
FYI: `salt` has deprecated as of >=PHP 7.0.0

Comment: Your question is too broad, you need to narrow it down. And the way the password is hashed, should not have to do anything with your password reset mechanism.

Comment: generate a random string, store in the db, and use as part of the activate account link, eg http://example.com/activate?email=bob@work.com&code=fhgashfkvgh865r86kjghbv

Comment: `passhword_hash()` function in php cannot be decrypted. You can use `id` of user to using GET method and update the password of specific user. Give the link of file which accept GET value with update password mechaism. You can also use `base64encode()` in php to hide id from appearing in url.

Comment: This link may help you [link](https://technopoints.co.in/forgot-password-password-reset-system-in-php/)

Comment: `password_hash()` is one-way. You can't and shouldn't be able to decrypt it

Comment: I'm not clicking on that link

Comment: I use already password_verify to verify if an user use the right password to connect

Answer (score 0):

Using PHPMailer Here Sample of My Code Where $dir is your current directory

```
function mailSet($to,$full_name,$subject,$body){
    require($dir.'vendor/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    require($dir.'vendor/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'YOUR HOST';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

    $mail->Username = 'HOST EMAIL ACCOUNT'; 
    $mail->Password = 'HOST PASSWORD'; 

    $mail->From = 'FROM EMAIL';
    $mail->setFrom('FROM EMAIL', 'FULL NAME');

    $mail->AddAddress($to, $full_name);
    $mail->WordWrap = 70;

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    $mail->IsHTML(TRUE);


    if(!$mail->Send()){
      echo 'SEND';
    } else {
     echo 'FAILED TO SEND';        }
}

function forgetPassword($account){
  global $dir;
  $data=getData('users',$account); //GET DATA FROM DATABASE
  $link=getDataBy('forget_password','account',$data['id']); //RELATION DATA FROM TABLE USERS
  $body='SOME TEXT <p>YOU CAN USE HTML TAG TO <a href="'.$dir.'login/changepassword?SESSION_ID='.$link['link'].'&&SESSION_VALID='.md5(rand(0,100)).'">LINK TO CLICK</a><p>END OF HTML TAG</p>';
  return $body;
}`
```

Sample PHP Mail Using PHPMailer, Where $to = Recipient Email, $full_name = Recipient Full Name, $subject = Email Subject, $body = EMAIL HTML BODY

Answer (score 0):

> to decrypt a password is not recommended

If it is even theoretically possible to decrypt your passwords then you are doing it wrong.

Further, from your description, you are creating an easily exploited denial of service vulnerability if you allow passwords to be changed anonymously. The right solution is:

- When someone asserts an identity and requests a password reset, generate a token with high redundancy and a limited TTL, email that to the user. Do NOT change the password.
- When a reset token is presented along with a username, validate the TTL has not expired and that the token was issued to the asserted username, then allow the user to pick a new password.

Comment: Thx for the information, i understand itsn't recommended and i won't use it...i will use the way to send my mail a link to change the password associate link + user

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="send_link.php">
      <p>Enter Email Address To Send Password Link</p>
      <input type="text" name="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit_email">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Step 1.Make a HTML file and define markup for password reset system

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_email']) && $_POST['email'])
{
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('sample');
  $select=mysql_query("select email,password from user where email='$email'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($select)==1)
  {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
      $email=md5($row['email']);
      $pass=md5($row['password']);
    }
    $link="<a href='www.samplewebsite.com/reset.php?key=".$email."&reset=".$pass."'>Click To Reset password</a>";
    require_once('phpmail/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  
    // GMAIL username
    $mail->Username = "your_email_id@gmail.com";
    // GMAIL password
    $mail->Password = "your_gmail_password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
    // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Port = "465";
    $mail->From='your_gmail_id@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName='your_name';
    $mail->AddAddress('reciever_email_id', 'reciever_name');
    $mail->Subject  =  'Reset Password';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Body    = 'Click On This Link to Reset Password '.$pass.'';
    if($mail->Send())
    {
      echo "Check Your Email and Click on the link sent to your email";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Step 2.Make a PHP file to send the link

```
<?php
if($_GET['key'] && $_GET['reset'])
{
  $email=$_GET['key'];
  $pass=$_GET['reset'];
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('sample');
  $select=mysql_query("select email,password from user where md5(email)='$email' and md5(password)='$pass'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($select)==1)
  {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="submit_new.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <p>Enter New password</p>
    <input type="password" name='password'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_password">
    </form>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Step 3.Make a PHP file to reset Password

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_password']) && $_POST['key'] && $_POST['reset'])
{
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $pass=$_POST['password'];
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('sample');
  $select=mysql_query("update user set password='$pass' where email='$email'");
}
?>
```

Step 4.Make a PHP file to update new password

Comment: Sorry, but about everything here is wrong: Sql injection, plain-text passwords (or md5, which is not much better), deprecated (non-existing in php 7+) `mysql_*` functions, etc.

Comment: yes sir you are right but  i think md5() is good for encryption because it is non decryptable in php

Comment: You replaced a solid hashing tool with `md5()`? Why?

Comment: "non decryptable in php" - you don't understand the problem domain. You might start addressing this by reading up on rainbow tables, extension attacks and salting.

Comment: All my input are protected by this method :
`$patternUser = "#^[0-9a-z]([0-9a-z]{0,13})[0-9a-z]$#";
    if (!preg_match($patternUser, $champInitial['user'])) {
        $champInitial['champInvalid'] = true;`